# Multidimensional Map

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm creating a trigger to do some validations and I have a map that is Country_Key__c, Description_Name__c, Name.  I would like to get them all into a map so I can do some validations.  I have googled and search this form for some answers, but I am very new to Salesforce and Apex and do not grasp many of the concepts..  I would like to create these maps to do be multidimensional..

```
Map<String, Validation_Country__c> validCountries = new Map<String, Validation_Country__c>();
Map<String, Validation_Region__c> validRegions = new Map<String, Validation_Region__c>();

//Creating Region and Country Lists... Need these to be multidimensional
For(Validation_Country__c obj : [Select Id,Country_Name__c,Transportation_Zone__C FROM Validation_Country__c]){
    validCountries.put( obj.Country_Name__c,obj);
}


 For(Validation_Region__c objR : [Select Id,Country_Key__c,Description__c,Name FROM Validation_Region__c]){
    validRegions.put( objR.Description__c,objR);
    validRegions.put( objR.Country_Key__c,objR);
}

For( Sampling__c s : Trigger.new){
    IF(s.Country__c != null){
        IF(validRegions.containsKey(s.Country__c) && (validRegions.contains(s.State_Province__c)){//Not quite right.. logic? 
            s.Country__c == validCountries.get(s.Country__c);//Wrong needs fixing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to fix the formatting .. Sorry!

Comment: So you're checking if the country__c and region__c field for the sampling__c object are valid by checking the values against the values stored in other object, this is the validation that you're performing, correct?

Comment: Kind of..  Country__c is pretty straight forward but when it comes to Region__c(In this case more like States/Provinces) it gets complicated, because I have to make sure that for instance.. If the Country__c is US it can only have one of the 50 states..  There are other issues which I think I grasp, I just don't understand how to make a Map into a multidimensional one.  I Do have two objects Validation_Country__c which holds Country_Name__c,Transportation_Zone__C and Validation_Region__c which holds Country_Key__c,Description__c(states/provinces),Name

Comment: Is this going to cut the mustard - `Map <String, Map <String, SObject__c>> ()`?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what that line of code is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, have a look at the [State and Country Picklists](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm&language=en_US) from the Winter '14 release. You might be able to save yourself a lot of effort.

---

If you need something from the `Validation_Country__c` records keep your existing `validCountries` Map.

Then modify your `validRegions` map so that is has an extra "dimension" for countries.

```
// Top level map is keyed by Country. Inner Map is keyed by Region
Map<String, Map<String, Validation_Region__c>> validRegions = new Map<String, Map<String, Validation_Region__c>>();

// ...

for(Validation_Region__c objR : [Select Id,Country_Key__c,Description__c,Name FROM Validation_Region__c]){

    string countryKey = objR.Country_Key__c;

    Map<String, Validation_Region__c> regionMap = validRegions.get(countryKey);
    // Maybe rework to use Map.containsKey rather than null check. Would be cleaner.
    if(regionMap == null) {
        regionMap = new Map<String, Validation_Region__c>();
        validRegions.put(countryKey, regionMap);
    }
    string regionKey = objR.Description__c; 
    regionMap.put(regionKey, objR);
}


for( Sampling__c s : Trigger.new){
    if(s.Country__c != null){
        string countryKey = s.Country__c;
        string regionKey = s.State_Province__c;

        if(validCountries.containsKey(countryKey) && validRegions.containsKey(countryKey)) {
        // The country appears to be valid and there are possible Region matches
        Validation_Country__c vc = validCountries.get(countryKey);

        if(validRegions.get(countryKey).containsKey(regionKey)) {
            // The Region belongs to the country
            Validation_Region__c vr = validRegions.get(countryKey).get(regionKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great, I will give this it a try.  Sadly I couldn't use pick lists due to restraints though.. thank you!

Comment: Hi Daniel, couple quick questions it was my understanding as a young programmer to never declare variables inside a For Loop, so does that hold true for this case? string countryKey = objR.Country_Key__c; Also at line 18 validRegions.put( regionKey,objR); I am unable to do this because it is an incompatiable value type SObject:Validation_Region__c for Map

Comment: "never declare variables inside a For Loop" - That comes down to how the variable is used, scope requirements, and if you or the compiler are doing the optimizations. In this case I prefer minimal scope and clarity over questionable performance optimizations.

Comment: I've fixed line 18 to `regionMap.put(regionKey, objR);`. It should be going into the nested map.

Comment: Hi Daniel, One more question for you.  On my Validation_Country__c I have what is called a SAP Transportation Zone which in many cases is very similar to the actual country.  This field is 1 to 1 so I was just going to make it auto populate whenever someone would put in a country.  Would it be as simple as adding String transZone = s.SAP_Transportation_Zone__c?  That is why I put in that first For loop for Valid_Countries__c,  Sorry about keeping this topic still open

Comment: If you have a one-to-one mapping you might be able to use a formula field to automatically expose the value via a relationship. Best to ask another question an clearly state the problem and what you have tried so far.